# Odd issue,Wubi Installation won't boot, when another ext4 drive is plugged?

Tags: 11.04, wubi, hard-drive, ext4

It's an odd issue, i installed Ubuntu 11.04 trough Wubi yesterday,it actually worked unlike the last time i tried to when it didn't boot at all.

But there is one thing that bugs me, see, i have 2 HDD's ,a 320GB one with Windows 7, and the other, a 500GB HDD with Ubuntu 10.10.

I have partitioned the 500GB HDD, and contains a NTFS partition, and a EXT4 plus the Swap partitions.

The 320GB is not partitioned, as it only has Windows 7.

Since i installed Wubi on Windows 7, when i have my Ubuntu drive connected, Wubi won't boot the installation, giving me a "no wubdir" error.

However, if i phisically unplug the Ubuntu drive, then Wubi boots just fine.

So, how is the Ubuntu drive interfering with Wubi, to the extent of Wubi not even working when the drive is plugged?.

Comment: so.. no one experimenting this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wubi uses grub4dos to boot (wubildr.mbr). The version of grub4dos is from around 2007 which is before ext4 was released. In any event, wubildr.mbr will hang whenever it encounters an ext4 partition.
The way it works is to search each partition (in BIOS order) for the file /wubildr (i.e. wubildr in the root of the partition). If it gets to the ext4 partition before it finds /wubildr, it will hang. So the solution is to copy /wubildr from your 320GB drive to the ntfs partitions on the 500GB drive, assuming it falls before the ext4 one - if not, the only way would be to add an entry to your other Ubuntu so that you can boot the Wubi install from there.

Comment: I do want to get round to fixing this.  The code differences in grub4dos are not that large, so it should be feasible; but in any case what I actually want to do is switch to grub2's ntldr-img extras module, which is based on grub4dos but is somewhere that the GRUB team can maintain it.  To do that I need to go through the differences between grub4dos and ntldr-img and resolve them all.  I plan to do that for Oneiric.

Answer (score 0):

you should be carefully to follow the instruction, where you download with Wubi, and download to complete, so you can where click and user, etcc, then done, click reboot with restart, then boost windows 7 and ubuntu, then click ubuntu, just leave waiting until appear ubuntu desktop, that's all.

Comment: if i understand you what you said, Wubi installs fine, and i can boot to it, ,but i can only do this by unpluggin, phisically my other HDD.If the drive is plugged to the PC wubi won't boot